# Join Two Column into New Column

Tags: sql, oracle

How do I combine both COLUMN2 of table1 and table2?

```
SELECT COLUMN1, COLUMN2 FROM TABLE1
C1 C2
A  1


SELECT COLUMN1, COLUMN2 FROM TABLE2
C1 C2
A  1
B  2
C  2


C1 C2 C3
A  1  1
B  2  0
C  2  0
```

I want to have a third column combining column2 of both tables base on column1 which has a value of A, B, C. Then if it's null in either table the value should be 0 Please see third sample for sample result.

Comment: Add (d,3) to table1, and (e, 4) to table2, and adjust the result accordingly.

Comment: I don't understand your answer.

Comment: It's not an answer. The question is not clear, but if you follow my tip, it will become easier to understand it.

Comment: what is mean by Combining which of the value showed in C2 from your result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you want to match records from both tables on the basis of key column `COLUMN1`. If a record exists in only one table display that. `COLUMN3` indicates whether the key exists in both tables.

This solution uses `FULL OUTER JOIN`, so it will work whether a record exists in `T1` but not `T2` or in `T2` but not `T1`. The `coalesce()` function displays the first non-null argument.

```
SELECT coalesce(t1.COLUMN1, t2.COLUMN1) as COLUMN1
       , coalesce(t1.COLUMN2, t2.COLUMN2) as COLUMN2
       , case when t1.COLUMN1 is not null 
                   and t2.COLUMN1 is not null then 1 else 0 end as  COLUMN3
FROM TABLE1 t1
     full outer join TABLE2 t2
     on t1.COLUMN1 =  t2.COLUMN1
```

Assumption. This query ignores the scenario where `t1.COLUMN1 =  t2.COLUMN1` but `t1.COLUMN2 !=  t2.COLUMN2`. It will just show `t1.COLUMN2` in the result set. If this is not the outcome you desire please **edit your question ** to include more sample data and the full required output.

Answer (score 0):

This is what you must be looking for

```
 SELECT tbl1.C1,
       tbl2.C2,
       [C3] =
(
    SELECT CASE
               WHEN tbl1.C2 Is Null OR tbl2.C2 is null 
               THEN 0
               ELSE 1
           END
)
FROM tbl1
     INNER JOIN tbl2 ON tbl1.C1 = tbl2.C1;
```

Answer (score 0):

To avoid confusion, lets say table_1 has 2 columns(C1,C2) and table_2 has 2 columns(C3,C4). I just renamed column 1 & 2 of table_2 to column 3 & 4.

From What I understood from your question you want all records of table_2 in the result along with a new column which contains values from table_1 based c3 column.

The requires `Table_1 right outer join Table_2` with NVL to display 0 against which value is missing in table_1 (B & C)

Full Query is as follows

```
SELECT Y.COLUMN_3, Y.COLUMN_4, NVL (X.COLUMN_2, 0)
FROM TABLE_1 X RIGHT OUTER JOIN TABLE_2 Y ON (X.COLUMN_1 = Y.COLUMN_3);
```

Hope this answers your query. Please mark the answer accepted if this solves your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
select table2.c1,
       table2.c2,
case when table1.c2 is null or
table2.c2 is null 
then 0 else 1 end c3
from table1,table2 where table1.c1(+)=table2.c1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code...

```
select dbo.Table_2.C1,
       dbo.Table_2.C2,
       [C3] = (select Case when dbo.Table_1.C2 = dbo.Table_2.C2 then 1 else 0 end)
from dbo.Table_2
left join dbo.Table_1 on dbo.Table_1.C1 = dbo.Table_2.C1
```